# Sending weekly emails using MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I'm searching a way to send emails via MySql, similar to using dbmail in SQL Server.

I am writing a query to be emailed every week but for the life of me I cannot find any information on sending emails using only MySQL. All solutions I've come across uses php to send the actually email, which I don't think I'd want seeing as I want to schedule it to send an email every week.

Is it possible to send emails via mySQL?
Is there a better way to implement this?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Development Tools: WAMP Server, MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 0):

You could create a batch/Powershell script that executes on a schedule (using the Windows scheduling assistant).

Whilst this isn't the way I'd perhaps do it (Maybe a PHP Cron Job for example) - it is certainly a way of doing it without PHP

Is there a reason you don't want to use PHP?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I wanted it to be something I could schedule to run weekly, I didn't think I would be able to do that within PHP.

But if it's possible I can give it a shot. A friend mentioned to do it in PHP have write a perl script to execute the php script whenever I need it to.

I will look into that Cron Job you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

To Schedule events on MySQL you can flow this tutorial.

http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-create-mysql-events/

To send e-mail you can use MySQL UDF (https://github.com/mysqludf)

Here is a tutorial 
http://dailypaper.in/technical/how-to-send-email-from-a-mysql-trigger-in-linux/

hope this can help you